# Insert from temporary table adding identity

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, identity, bulkinsert

I have imported in a temporary table several rows from a csv file using bulk insert on SQL Server. I had to import on a temp table because the primary key ID was not present in the CSV file.

Now I would like to transfer the data on the real table; but I can't because I  can't find the way to add the id.

I have tried:

```
INSERT INTO companies (id, code, name, vat_code, ce_vat_code, fiscal_code, 
    address, zip_code)
SELECT IDENTITY(INT) AS id, code, name, vat_code, ce_vat_code, 
    fiscal_code, address, zip_code
FROM   temp_companies
```

but I get this error:

```
The IDENTITY function can only be used when the SELECT statement has an INTO 
clause.
```

Comment: is `companies.id` already an `identity()` column?

Comment: yes, in create statement: id BIGINT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL,

Comment: Shouldn't select it then, will get filled in automagically

Answer (score 1):

if `companies.id` is an `identity()` column, you do not need to insert a value for that column:

```
INSERT INTO companies (code, name, vat_code, ce_vat_code, fiscal_code, address, zip_code)
SELECT code, name, vat_code, ce_vat_code, fiscal_code, address, zip_code
FROM   temp_companies
```

if `companies.id` is not an `identity()` or `sequence` with a default for `next value for`, you can add a `row_number()` to the `max()` `id` from `companies`:

```
INSERT INTO companies (id, code, name, vat_code, ce_vat_code, fiscal_code, address, zip_code)
SELECT m.maxid + row_number() over (order by (select 1))
  , code, name, vat_code, ce_vat_code, fiscal_code, address, zip_code
FROM   temp_companies
cross join (select max(id) as maxid from companies) m
```

Comment: I tried the second option, (I was wrong, companies table has not id set as identity()). but I get the following error: `Invalid column name 'id'.`

Comment: @Argentina Updated to order by `(select 1)` in the `row_number()`

Answer (score 1):

You cannot manually insert the value into `identity column`. That is surrogate key which is generated by system. Only if you `set identity insert` ON then you could insert the values but still not entire `identity`.

You need to default that column `id` as `identity` when you create it. If the column is not identity now, you need to re-create the table with that default added.

**UPDATE** since you have already had that column as `identity` column, just skip insert that column, insert the rest of filed, that `id` will be populated automatically.

Comment: Actually you can insert identity values if you set IDENTITY_INSERT ON for that table. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql And it isn't a surrogate key. If the column allows duplicates there is nothing that says an identity must be unique. Of course, most of the time we see this set as the primary key.

Comment: thx @SeanLange, for the first part, I did metaioned xD, thanks for correct me the later part